# Javascript - How Do I make an array out of all beginning and end string match instances - found in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

I have a **string** like this:

```
var My_string = "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div><div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div><div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div><div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>";
```

I want to **search** through the **string** and and add each full div found to an array.

So I want to **search** in the **string** for:

```
"<div"
```

and then:

```
"</div>"
```

and grab the text in-between:

```
var My_Div_Value = "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div>";
```

and push each onto an array:

```
My_Divs_Array.push(My_Div_Value);
```

So My_Divs_Array will have:

```
["<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div>", "<div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div>", "<div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div>", "<div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>"]
```

I'm just not sure the best way to go about this.
I imagine using "**IndexOf()**" or maybe I'm not sure.
I'd just like to ask the pro's what is the best way to achieve this.

---

From the intial responses - I'm not sure my post is understood.
I could have easily used the string example:

```
var My_string = "<foo>everything in between</bar><foo>everything in between</bar><foo>everything in between</bar><foo>everything in between</bar>";
```

I need each instance of `"<foo>"` + `"everything in between"` +  `"</bar>"` to be collected separate as `"<foo>everything in between</bar>"` and stored into an array:

```
["<foo>everything in between</bar>", "<foo>everything in between</bar>", "<foo>everything in between</bar>", "<foo>everything in between</bar>"]
```

---

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
Ken

Comment: Using the DOM would make it a lot easier than just treating it as a string...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The best solution is mostly likely to use DOM methods, XML/HTML libraries, or something even more specific, rather than raw string processing.

Comment: The string is exactly like is - pulled in from MySQL database. I want these div's in a javascript array, to use as temporary memory. Some of these div's will be deleted - and then saved back as the same string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div><div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div><div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div><div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>";

var Array_Of_Divs = str.split(/(?=<div )/);

alert(Array_Of_Divs);
```

produces:

```
["<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div>", "<div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div>", "<div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div>", "<div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>"];
```

Exactly what I was asking for : )

Thanks very much to :
Namida Aneskans
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1662018/namida-aneskans
[javascript - split without losing the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721844/javascript-split-without-losing-the-separator)

Answer (score 2):

Use DOM instead.

```
var My_string = "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div><div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div><div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div><div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>";

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = My_string;

console.log(wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div')); // get all the div
console.log(wrapper.getElementById('some_id_1')); // if you know the id
```

Or with jQuery.

```
$(My_string)
```

Comment: Thanks xdazz - Hmmmmmm, Maybe I'm not getting your answer - or I did not post the question correct. The div's are not in a webpage - they are in a string.

Comment: I will not know the id - that is why I thought the only logical way to pull each whole div out - would be to identify each "<div" and "</div>" and grab everything in between. That would give me each full div separate.

Comment: @kdawg You can DOM to manipulate strings. What xdazz is doing is to load the string into DOM, from which you can use the DOM methods getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 0):

To add to xdazz's response:

```
var My_string = "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div><div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div><div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div><div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>";

var wrapper = document.createElement('div'); Creates a DOM object.
wrapper.innerHTML = My_string; // Loads the string into DOM as HTML.
var objs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div'); // Get all the objects (each div tag element).

var My_Divs_Array; // Declare your output array.
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) { // Iterate through array of div elements.
    My_Divs_Array.push(objs[i].outerHTML); // Push the entire text portion of the div elements into array My_Divs_Array.
}
// Do what you want with My_Divs_Array, which now holds the strings that you want.
```

You don't need to do anything with the webpage itself. You're only using DOM and its HTML element parsing methods to deal with your string.

Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML

Edited.

Comment: Thanks for your example Stegrex
But your example produces :

"Some Div Text 1", "Some Div Text 2", "Some Div Text 3", "Some Div Text 4"

I am looking for the result:
"<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div>", "<div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div>", "<div id='some_id_3'>Some Div Text 3</div>", "<div id='some_id_4'>Some Div Text 4</div>"

Comment: I need the full div string for each div - "<div id='some_id_1'>Some Div Text 1</div>", "<div id='some_id_2'>Some Div Text 2</div>", etc. Not the div names or id's or inner html - but the whole HTML for each div

Comment: @kdawg OK, I think I understand what you need now. Check out outerHTML rather than innerHTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML