# javascript - split without losing the separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Split without losing character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047201/javascript-split-without-losing-character)

I have a string:

```
"<foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar>"
```

I want to separate all instances of "abcdefg" into an array like this:

```
["<foo>abcdefg</bar>", "<foo>abcdefg</bar>", "<foo>abcdefg</bar>", "<foo>abcdefg</bar>"];
```

I try:

```
var str="<foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar>";
var Array_Of_FooBars = str.split("</bar>"); 

alert(Array_Of_FooBars);
```

But it returns:

```
["<foo>abcdefg", "<foo>abcdefg", "<foo>abcdefg", "<foo>abcdefg",]
```

It is removing the separator ''. I don't want that.

How can I use split and not lose the separators from the string?

Thanks.
Ken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047201/javascript-split-without-losing-character?rq=1

Comment: You have a string of XML/HMTL elements like `<foo>abcdefg</bar>`? I don't think so. (Translation: It really is counter-productive when you make up the code you ask a question about. Also, your question reads: *"I want to do X on Y in order to have Z."* It actually should read *"I have Y and want Z, how can I do it?"* - `split()` is not the only possible solution.)

Comment: Thanks Tomalak - very helpful -_- if you don't know the answer -why bother with your negative response?

Comment: @kdawg: Your tags are wrong, it is helpful...why not fix it?

Comment: the question is -how to use split without losing the seperator.

Comment: ok - hows this? I have a string "|jam|abcdef|jelly||jam|abcdef|jelly||jam|abcdef|jelly|" - how do I split with '|jelly|' and not lose the '|jelly|'?

Comment: My answer is not negative. It is critical. You question contains an obvious error which I am pointing out.

Comment: or how about this one? "JAMabcdefJELLYJAMabcdefJELLYJAMabcdefJELLY" - how do I split with 'JELLY' and not lose the 'JELLY' so I havean array like ["JAMabcdefJELLY", "JAMabcdefJELLY", "JAMabcdefJELLY"]?

Comment: your response is not towards the question - any values can be used in the example - the question is NOT - are the values in the string correct? The question IS - how to use split without losing the separator. why waste peoples time?

Comment: If you have this as your input, I don't understand why do you make up some crooked HTML? - You should not use regular expressions on XML/HTML. Ever. Especially not with JavaScript where there is a full-blown DOM parser at your fingertips. "But I still want to, so just answer the damn question" is not a good enough reason.

Comment: `"<foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar>".split('</bar>').join('</bar>sep').split('sep');`. Although it leaves last element as empty.

Comment: Tomalak, it is to get you to focus on the problem. It is just a string. The delimiters does not matter. What matters, as you can see by the correct response, was to focus on the actual problem, Which was very plain to see in the question above. The question of XML or HTML or Klingon, is not the problem in this case - the problem was >>>>>>> losing the separator when using split()<<<<<<< Everyone else here saw the question and put forward a relative answer - except you - you continue to waste space on this message system with irrelevant questions and comments. Your first comment was also rude.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this. It's not a perfect solution, but it should work in most cases.

```
str.split(/(?=<foo>)/)
```

That is, split it in the position before each opening tag.

**EDIT:** You could also do it with `match()`, like so:

```
str.match(/<foo>.*?<\/bar>/g)
```

Comment: Excellent Namida Aneskans - exactly what I was asking. Thank you very much dude : )

Comment: And very good to know that the '.match() method will work as well.
thanks again Namida Aneskans : ) I think I like the match - as it seems there would be less room for error - matching everything on one end and the other and grabbing everything in-between? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would most likely want to use match:

```
var s = "<foo>abcd1efg</bar><foo>abc2defg</bar><foo>abc3defg</bar><foo>abc4defg</bar>"
s.match(/(<foo>.+?<\/bar>)/g)
// =>["<foo>abcd1efg</bar>", "<foo>abc2defg</bar>", "<foo>abc3defg</bar>", "<foo>abc4defg</bar>"]
```

Comment: I dig this, I deleted my answer to +1 this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over a simple regular expression and build the array that way:

```
var x = new RegExp('<foo>(.*?)</bar>', 'ig'),
s = "<foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar><foo>abcdefg</bar>",
matches = [];

while (i = x.exec(s)) {
    matches.push(i[0]);
}
```

Just realized using `String.match()` would be better; this code would be more useful for matching the contents inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use [positive lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) so that the regular expression asserts that the special character exists, but does not actually match it:

```
string.split(/<br \/>(?=&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)/g);
```

Comment: OK -sounds good. Where would I put the '</bar>' separator in your example?