# How to preserve dot using split and negative lookahead

Tags: javascript

I would like preserve dots using split function.

**string exemple :**

```
var str = "oqisjdf qosdifjq. fqs and the, fo. osidfo tchim cth."
```

**If I use str.split('.'), I'll obtain :**

```
["oqisjdf qosdifjq", " fqs and the, fo", " osidfo tchim cth", ""]
```

**but this is what I need :**

```
["oqisjdf qosdifjq.", " fqs and the, fo.", " osidfo tchim cth."]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string into array without deleting delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503827/split-string-into-array-without-deleting-delimiter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - split without losing the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721844/javascript-split-without-losing-the-separator)

Answer (score 4):

You could split by a positive lookbehind.

```js
var string = "oqisjdf qosdifjq. fqs and the, fo. osidfo tchim cth.",
    array = string.split(/(?<=\.)/);

console.log(array);
```